# how to install and run propel2 in windows with wamp or ampps

Tags: php, orm, wamp, propel, propel2

I would like to use propel 2, using the .zip file  in windows but I can't make it work according the docs[1](http://propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation.html) (I use wamp and ampps, different servers)
so I unzipped the file inside my WWW folder in my (wamp) server
I try to call http://server/test/propel/bin/propel.php
and i get a 500 error page; watching the php log file I see:

> - PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder' not found in ...\bin\propel.php on line 16
> - PHP Stack trace:
> - PHP   1. {main}() ...\propel.php:0

then i tried use the command line; and I set the PHPBIN variable to my php folder ('cause that one didn't exists in my environment)
run the propel.bat and I get:

> ..\php5.5 is not reconigzed as a internal or external command ...

but then the docs didn't mention how to proceed afterwards for configure the connection

please, did anybody try this?
what should I do??

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install it via composer? It's heavily recommanded as propel2 have a lot of dependancies, and it's a kinda complicated setup. 
http://propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation.html#via-composer
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Anyway, once installed (in your project, you have a vendor/bin/propel file), open console in your project root directory and use :

```
vendor\bin\propel init
vendor\bin\propel sql:build
```

I guess without composer, you have no bin in your vendor folder.
If so, and you installed it via zip, you might need to go to folder vendor/propel directly and then in console :

```
bin\propel init
bin\propel sql:build
```

Good luck, I remember not figuring it out right away either despite using composer.

Comment: it seems there is no way to install propel using only the zip file, nontheless its docs say otherwise.

Comment: thanks a lot, @anarkopsykotik.
but can i have composer in my developmetn machine and the php server(wamp) in another one? and how i'm gonna make it to generate its models from the .js file??? i'm very confused...

Comment: Composer is just a dependency manager, it will fetch all needed libraries for the project from it's config file, and put it in "vendor" folder. Once done, you can indeed copy it from your dev machine to your server. Don't forget to include the generated "autoloading.php" in your setup script, so that all librairies are automatically loaded in your code.
The "init" command of propel will walk you through few steps to set up configuration of the connection to your DB, and then generate  classes/sql.

Comment: i appreciate your interest; finally i installed it as you suggested, i could make it run with the INIT, now i struggling with the BUILD...

but thank you too much!!!